# How do I find the average for every minute of measurement for a certain group of chr rows?

Tags: r, datetime, std, mean

I've been making some measurements with several sensors over a period of time. I now need to find the average and standard deviation across all 10 sensors every minute so I will eventually get a data frame with the following columns: Time, Average & Std. However, my problem arises due to the way that I receive my data. First of all, the sensors do not make the measurements at the exact same time but only approximately every minute for all of them. This makes it difficult to identify an exact timestamp for which I need the average. Furthermore, since the sensors measure several variables, the ID of the sensor is given in one single column, thus it can not just take the average of all the columns as these express different variables instead of the different sensors. See picture below.

[image: The data set I'm working with]

Is there anyway that I can solve this problem? In other words I need a mean (and std) function where I can tell it 1) which variable to mean (e.g. T), 2) which Entity Names to mean across (e.g. ANG5-00902 and ANG5-00903) and 3) to do it for every HH:MM

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide the sample of your data frame with ```dput()```. It makes things easier for everyone.

Comment: @Shibaprasadb Thank you for the tip! As you might have guessed I'm all new in both R and stack overflow, hence I'm a little bit confused as to what you mean. Can you elaborate on it? Is it something I need to type in to R as dput(df) in order to visualize my data in a certain way? I've tried this but it gives me an error.

Comment: @Sorensen The way you have shared your data (an image) means it is not possible for us to replicate your issue, as we can't paste an image into your console. It is **much** easier if you type in ``dput(name_of_your_data)`` to your R session and **paste all the output directly into your question**, so that we can replicate your data.

Comment: @user438383 Ah, that makes very much sense. Thank you for clarifying. However, when I paste it into the question it is just a lot of numbers in row. How do I insert it so that you as readers can make sense of it?

Comment: @Sorensen that’s fine - a lot of numbers in a row is how it should look - it can be pasted directly into our console and it will exactly replicate your data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it in a function you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

meanstd <- function(df, filter, var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(format(as.POSIXct(Timestamp), format = "%H:%M"), Filter.x) %>%
    filter(Entity.Name %in% filter) %>%
    summarize(Mean = mean(get(var)),
              Std = sd(get(var))) %>%
    ungroup()
}

meanstd(X20210913NewAirNode, c("ANG5-00902", "ANG5-00903"), "T")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. When I use you code, R returns: 

Mistake in UseMethod("group_by") :  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"

I'm not quite sure what to do about this. Can you help me out?

Comment: Please try to use `dplyr::group_by`. I think you are using a similar function from another package

Comment: Like this? `library(dplyr)

meanstd <- function(X20210913NewAirNode, filter, var) {
  X20210913NewAirNode %>%
    dplyr::group_by(format(as.POSIXct(Timestamp), format = "%H:%M"), Filter.x) %>%
    filter(Entity.Name %in% filter) %>%
    summarize(Mean = mean(get(var)),
              Std = sd(get(var))) %>%
    ungroup()
}

meanstd(df, c("ANG5-00902", "ANG5-00903"), "T")`

It gives me the same warning as before.

Comment: I see you changed part of the function. There is no need to put the column name in the `function()`. If you want to call to the table `X20210913NewAirNode` you can do that in the `meanstd()` call at the end. I will add that in my original answer as well

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble. I'm completely new in R and haven't used function before. I thought I needed to insert `X20210913NewAirNode` as this is the name of my data frame. When I substitute this so that my code is completely similar to yours it still gives me the same error though.

Comment: Did you insert `X20210913NewAirNode` into the last line?